# Finding number of unique elements in the list

Tags: prolog

I want to write a code which will return number of unique elements in the list. My idea is to check if head of the list is there in the list of uniqeue elemeents. If it is not, add it to the list and increment the counter and continue witht the remaining list. So, I tried out following:

```
count([],0).
count([X,T], N) :- 
    count([X,T], [], N). %initially list of unique elements is empty

count([X,T], U, N) :- % U is a list of unique elements
    (not(member(X, U)), append(U, X, U2));
    count(T, U2, N1),
    N is N1 + 1.

%------ helpers ------
member_(X,[Y|T]):-
    member_(X, T).
member_(X,[X|_]).

append([], Y, [Y]).  % append[] and Y to get Y.
append([H|X], Y, [H|Z]) :- append(X, Y, Z). % append [H|X] and Y to get [H|Z] if appending X and Y gives Z
```

But running above simply return `false`:

```
3 ?- count([1,2,3],N).
   Call: (10) count([1, 2, 3], _7714) ? creep
   Fail: (10) count([1, 2, 3], _7714) ? creep
false.
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But running above simply return false:
>
> ```
> 3 ?- count([1,2,3],N).
>    Call: (10) count([1, 2, 3], _7714) ? creep
>    Fail: (10) count([1, 2, 3], _7714) ? creep
> false.
> ```
>
> Why is this so?

Because there is no head of a clause that `count([1,2,3],N)` can match.

You have two clauses for count/2:

```
count([],0).             %%% clause 1
count([X,T], N) :- ...   %%% clause 2
```

Since `[1,2,3]` can't be unified with `[]`, clause 1 is no match.
But `[1,2,3]` can also not be unified with `[X,T]`, thus clause 2 is also no match. Therefore, `count([1,2,3],N)` cannot be proven.

You can test this by asking

```
?- [X,T]=[1,2,3].
false.
```

What you need to recursively break down lists of arbitrary length is `[X|T]` instead. (Please test `?- [X|T]=[1,2,3].` to see how you could fix your code.)

Comment: yess got the silly mistake , but now the issue is resolved, but due to disjunction `;`, the last two statements `count(T, U2, N1), N is N1 + 1.` are not getting executed. How do I fix this?

Comment: I recommend not to use ";" too much, especially not, if you are just starting to learn prolog. I would recommend for you to write a separate clause for each possible case. I am curious what you come up with :-)

Comment: @Rnj to resolve your **new** issue please post a **new** question while marking **this** post's issue as resolved by *accepting* the answer that was most helpful in resolving it.